# Is the Inputmetrics.recordsRead on the Executor metrics an exact count on RDD/Dataframe lines?

Tags: apache-spark

I've been checking the executor metrics offered by spark and would like to know if these metrics are exact and guaranteed. The recordRead metrics seems to be implemented with an accumulator and accumulators are guaranteed when run inside an action, this is the case with this metric ?. Do someone knows how this metric is calculated ?.

I've tried to replicate this metric using an accumulator and increasing it with a foreach but I'm worried about the shuffle generated by the foreach operation. I could replace that with a map but in this case the result of the accumulator will not be guaranteed.

Thanks in advance for your help

regards,